# Error while trying to plot a white circle inside a black box

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

this code provied a black box with a white circle inside, I get an error, which I added below the code
I'm trying to draw a white circle inside a black box using matplotlib using this code:

```
class Circle:
    def __init__(self, resolution, radius, position):
        self.resolution = resolution
        self.radius = radius
        self.position = (position[0], position[1])
        self.output = []
    
    def draw(self):
        box = np.zeros((self.resolution, self.resolution))
        s = (self.radius * 2, self.radius * 2)
        xv, yv = np.meshgrid(np.arange(s[0]), np.arange(s[1]))
        r = np.abs((xv) ** 2 + (yv) ** 2 - self.radius ** 2)
        self.output = np.ones(r)
        circumference_cir = self.output
        return (circumference_cir)
    
    def show(self):
        image = self.output
        plt.imshow(image)


obg = Circle(resolution= 16, radius= 2, position= (2,4))
obg.draw()
obg.show()
```

and I have this error:

```
       1 obg = Circle(resolution= 16, radius= 2, position= (2,4))
 ----> 2 obg.draw()
       3 obg.show()
 

 ---> 16         self.output = np.ones(r)
     17         circumference_cir = self.output
     18         return (circumference_cir)
 

 --> 192     a = empty(shape, dtype, order)
     193     multiarray.copyto(a, 1, casting='unsafe')
     194     return a
 
 TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar
 index.
```

I guess there's something wrong with the conversion of array to a
list, but I'm not sure. I should only use numpy library.

Comment: `np.ones` is being called incorrectly, and it seems here you might want something like `self.output = r<0` instead of the `ones` line.

Answer (score 0):

The `np.ones` line in your code is being called incorrectly (`np.ones` needs a `size` tuple, not a large array).  Instead try replacing the `ones` line with something like,

```
self.output = r<0
```

This should take all of the points where `r<0`, that is, all the points within the radius, and set them to `1` and all the others to `0`.